# my pdf convert show nothing.. but i have datas in mysql.. (fpdf)

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

my codes are here ;

```
 require('pdf_creat/fpdf.php');
     include ('class/db.php');

    $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->SetFont('times','B',10);
    $pdf->Cell(25,7,"Stud ID");
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,"Student Name");
    $pdf->Cell(40,7,"Address");
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,"Class");
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,"Phone No");
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,"E-mail");
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(450,7,"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    $pdf->Ln();

    $sql = "select * from students";
    $result = dbConnect()->prepare($sql);

    $row=$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($rows=array_shift($row)) {                               
        $studid = $rows[0];
        $name = $rows[1];
        $address = $rows[2];
        $class = $rows[3];
        $phone = $rows[4];
        $email = $rows[5];
        $pdf->Cell(25,7,$studid);
        $pdf->Cell(30,7,$name);
        $pdf->Cell(40,7,$address);
        $pdf->Cell(30,7,$class);
        $pdf->Cell(30,7,$phone);
        $pdf->Cell(30,7,$email); 
        $pdf->Ln();                  
    }
    $pdf->Output();
```

I did simply the system but when i display, it show nothing. I want to display datas in mysql.. is there any error in my codes? I searched many answers but they did not satisfied me.. please anyone can say if I have any error or must I add any function between my codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, I don't know what include('class/db.php'); contains. I used PDO connection to test your case:

```
require('fpdf.php');



function getConnection() {
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbuser='root';
    $dbpass='';
    $dbname='testdb';
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}




$pdf=new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('times','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(25,7,"Stud ID");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"Student Name");
$pdf->Cell(40,7,"Address");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"Class");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"Phone No");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"E-mail");
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(450,7,"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
$pdf->Ln();

$sql = "select * from   students";

$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$db = null;

foreach($rows as $key=>$value){

    $studid = $value['studid'];
    $name = $value['name'];
    $address = $value['address'];
    $class = $value['class'];
    $phone = $value['phone'];
    $email = $value['email'];
    $pdf->Cell(25,7,$studid);
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,$name);
    $pdf->Cell(40,7,$address);
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,$class);
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,$phone);
    $pdf->Cell(30,7,$email);
    $pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->Output();
```

The only major change is the way the i loop over the pdo associative array. I am accessing the keys of each of the rows read from the db, so instead of

`$studid = $rows[0];`

I am accessing say the id

`$studid = $rows['id'];`